# How to add a keybinding for a user-action in "Remote Systems" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have to work on a remote codebase via ssh/sftp. "Remote Systems"-view and my remote project work well. Every now and then I have to trigger a command (npm run-script...) on the remote system. I have configured a "user action" in the "Remote Systems"-view that works like a charm.

Now I want to have a keyboard-shortcut to trigger this user action while I'm working in the editor. But I cannot find any related command in the Eclipse keybindings-editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find a proper solution but here is my current workaround:

1. I added a keybinding (F9) to pop-up the "Remote System". A remote folder must be selected here but Eclipse keeps the selection.
2. I defined the remote command of the "user action" with an absolute path so it works on every selected path/file.
3. My keyboard-shortcut is now: `F9, Right-Windows-Key, u, Enter`